# How to load a 32 bit value to a register with microblaze assembly

Tags: assembly, microblaze

I am looking at creating some code using the assembly language for the Microblaze and I dont know how to load the a general purpose register with a 32 bit number.  I went through the instruction set but only see 16 bit immediate values that can be loaded.

Can someone provide an example of how to do this.

I could used

```
shi r8 r0 %0  /* where %0 is to the top 16 bits of a variable */
then shift it ?
and then load r8 bottom bytes?
```

I am confused.  Any help to point me in the right direction would be great.

Comment: Google says Microblaze is a 32-bit RISC architecture.  A 32-bit constant would take up an entire instruction word, leaving no bits for an opcode or destination.  So like all other fixed-instruction-size architectures, you will need multiple instructions.  Most ISAs have a pair of instructions specifically for this, that make it easy to merge upper and lower halves.  Assemblers often have a pseudo-op that takes one 32-bit arg and emits both instructions.  But I don't know anything about Microblaze specifically.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Microblaze Refference Guide](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/mb_ref_guide.pdf):

> Type B instructions have one source register and a 16-bit immediate
>   operand (which can be extended to 32 bits by preceding the Type B
>   instruction with an imm instruction).

Which means, if you're writing in assembly language, you can use 32 bit immediate with no worries:

```
or r1, r0, 0x12345678
```

and assembler will expand it into:

```
imm 0x1234
or r1, r0, 0x5678
```